# Android Camera Intent

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I have a simple application that has a button that allows the user to enter the camera application by clicking it. It seems that things work fine if I were to take a picture having the tablet in landscape mode. It prompts the user to save or discard. After clicking save, it returns to my application.

However, when I attempted to capture a photo with a portrait mode, after clicking the save button, it will return to the camera application again.

Why is this so?

Comment: You need to add some code for others to help.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with your application.  By firing intent you are invoking camera application present on your device. Its behaviour out of your reach